# Check if WPF window is open

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I check wheher a window is open or not. Is it possible?

For example:

```
if (window.IsOpen)
{
    // window is open
}
else
{
    // window is not open
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by open? Shown? Not minimized?

Comment: i have menu bar with some menuitems  i want to check if other winform is allready shown (maby minimized or on backgraund) if it is allready opened to activate and dont open again

Answer (score 3):

You could retain a reference to the window when it's opened. In which case, you don't really need to go find it in the windows.
Otherwise, you'll have to get it based on the type of the given window.

```
        Window1 instance = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window1>().SingleOrDefault();
        if (instance !=null)
        {
            instance.Show();
        }
```

If this can be one of several types of window types and you need a generic approach then it's a bit more fiddly.
Here I have a fixed value for my type but you'd want a button per window, each with the type of that window.

```
        Type specificType = typeof(Window1);
        Window instance = null;
        foreach (Window win in Application.Current.Windows)
        {
            if(win.GetType() == specificType)
            {
                instance = win;
            }
        }
        if (instance != null)
        {
            instance.Show();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

To check if a window is shown in the current application:

```
if(System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows.Contains(yourWindow)) {
    // the window has been shown
} else {
    yourWindow.Show();
}
```

To check if a window is not minimized:

```
if(yourWindow.WindowState != WindowState.Minimized) {
    // the window is currently not minimized
} else {
    yourWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
    // or WindowState.Maximized
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
    if(Application.Current.Windows.OfType<YourType>().Any())  
    {
        var = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        var = 0;
    }
            
}
catch
{

}
```